# How to find inverse function for following logarithm function?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions, inverse-function

I am kind stuck with finding the inverse function of following function.

$$f:x\mapsto\log_2(x^2-3x-4)$$

Let $y =f(x)=\log_2 (x^2 - 3x-4)$. After I simplify the function, I end up with:
$2^x = y^2 - 3y -4$.
But literally what is the next step to do, but the answer surprisingly looks like this:

$$\begin{split}
f^{-1}(x)&=\frac{3+\sqrt{25+2^{x+2}}}{2}\quad\text{if }x>4\\
f^{-1}(x)&=\frac{3-\sqrt{25+2^{x+2}}}{2}\quad\text{if }x<-1\\
\end{split}$$

which seems like making quadratic formula, but have no clue on how the answer being derived.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DonAntonio partially did (though I think he should better have let you work). However, the answer written in your post is not correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval, sorry what is the problem with the answer I gave? that it taken from a textbook...

Comment: Let me first salvage the previous comments, now deleted, though necessary for anybody to understand the history of this post. 1) "Please edit your post to type math formulas instead of inserting enormous images that hurt the eyes." (me,+4) 2) "Please[...]tutorial." (DB,+1) 3) ""Hint": solve for $y∈{\rm dom}(f)=?$ the quadratic equation $y^2-3y-(4+2^x)=0.$" (me) 4) "@AnneBauval, thanks, fixed it. Do you. mind explain a little bit for your hint? Still confusing for a high school math skill person..." (you).

Comment: And finally (36 and 31 mins ago): 5) "@Don[...]not correct." (me) and 6) "@Anne[...]textbook..." (you). I just replied to 6) by editing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2-3x-4=(x+1)(x-4),$ the domain of $f$ is
$${\rm dom}(f)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x^2-3x-4>0\}=(-\infty,-1)\cup(4,+\infty).$$
The answer you reproduced from your textbook is doubly  wrong because

> $f:{\rm dom}(f)\to\Bbb R$ ([plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+log_2%28x%5E2-3x-4%29)) is *not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function),* and is *[surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).*

For *every* $y\in\Bbb R$ (so: not only for $y>4$ or $<-1$), there are exactly *two* values of $x\in{\rm dom}(f)$ such that $y=f(x)$ (not only one), namely: the two solutions $x_\pm$ of the [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)
$$x^2-3x-(4+2^y)=0,$$
i.e.
$$x_\pm=\frac{3\pm\sqrt\Delta}2,\text{ where }\Delta=(-3)^2+4(4+2^y)=25+2^{y+2}.$$
Note that these two values $x_{\pm}$ automatically belong to ${\rm dom}(f),$ since $x_\pm^2-3x_\pm-4=2^y>0.$

Comment: If $\;x>4\;$ or $\;x<-1\;$  then the function $\;f\;$ is injective as in the first case it is monotonically ascending and in the second case mon. descending, thus the inverse exists on each case separately (as the function is clearly onto its image). I think that was the intention of the question, which I agree is very poorly worded.

Comment: Yes, the restriction of $f$ to these two intervals is injective, as both the plot or the algebraic solution show ($x_+>4$ and $x_-<-1$). But the question is not only poorly worded, it is completely wrong. *There is no condition like $x>4$ or $x<-1$ for the existence of the so-called $f^{-1}(x)$* (which moreover has a meaning only for each of the two restrictions, not for $f$ itself). It exists for *every* real number $x.$ The knot in the brain of the author of the textbook probably occured when (s)he changed the usual notations $(x,y)$ to $(y,x).$

Comment: Je suis d'accord.

Answer (score 0):

The folloiwng can be tried always, though not always you get a nice output:

$$y=\log_2(x^2-3x-4)\implies2^y=x^2-3x-4\implies x^2-3x-(4+2^y)=0\;(*)$$

After we wrote the function as $y\;$ function of $\,x\;$ , we try the other way around: $\;x\;$ as function of $\;y\;$ . The above quadratic's discriminant:

$$\Delta=9+4(4+2^y)=25-4\cdot2^y=25+2^{y+2}$$

and the solutions are

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{25+2^{y+2}}}2\;\ldots$$

Now just interchange $\;x\leftrightarrow y\;$ to write the inverse in the usual way, and we're done.

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you mind explain to me a little bit how you come up to `Δ=9+4(4+2)=25−4⋅2=25+2+2`? Thank you!

Comment: @James That's the decriminant of the quadratic. Remember that for a quadratic $\;ax^2+bx+c\;$ its discriminant is $\;\Delta=b^2-4ac\;$ ...This is the term that goes into the square root in the quadratic equation's roots formula: $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\;,\;\;a\neq0$$ And of course: the corresponding (real) quadratic equation has real roots iff $\;\Delta\ge0\;$ .

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry just no very familiar with the variable. Last question, based on your method, the c doesn't matter in the quadratic formula, is that correct? For example, here the c could be any number as long as it doesn't produce a negative value for sqaure root? Sorry, I think I have some uncertain about the formula